# Sqlite3 : Unable to Authenticate

Tags: python, sqlite, flask

I'm creating an application in flask to learn python and sqlite3. What I'm facing problem is my login authentication is not checking database entries and allowing every user to log in. And user data is been stored in database at  the time of User signUp so database and tables are not empty. I have tried a lot but couldn't come up with any fix. Need some help

Here is the required piece of code.
problem is in '/login' block.

> app.py

```
def connect_db():
  return sqlite3.connect(DATABASE)

def init_db():
with closing(connect_db()) as db:
    with app.open_resource('schema.sql', mode='r') as f:
        db.cursor().executescript(f.read())
    db.commit()

@app.before_request
def before_request():
g.db = connect_db()

@app.teardown_request
def teardown_request(exception):
db = getattr(g, 'db', None)
if db is not None:
    db.close()

@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
error = None
#show = 10
if request.method == 'POST':
    username = request.form['username']
    password = request.form['password']
    cur = g.db.execute('select username,password from users where   
    username=? AND password=? ',[username,password])
    g.db.commit()

    if cur is None:
        error = 'No such user'
    else:
        session['logged_in'] = True
        flash('You are logged in')
        return redirect(url_for('show_entries'))
       # return ;

return render_template('login.html', error=error)
```

> Login.html

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block body %}
<h2>Login</h2>
{% if error %}<p class=error><strong>Error:</strong> {{ error }}{% endif %}
<form action="{{ url_for('login') }}" method=post>
<dl>
  <dt>Username:
  <dd><input  id="name" type=text name=username>
  <dt>Password:
  <dd><input  id="pass" type=password name=password>
  <dd><input id="login" type=submit value=Login>
  </dl>
  </form>
  {% endblock %}
```

Comment: You have to fix your html code: put the double quotes where required.

Comment: @doru can you point those areas for reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cur = g.db.execute` Will return a cursor object, this will never be `None`.

Instead you should check if you got any resulting rows.
`if cur.fetchone() is None:`

But you should probably check the documentation for how to perform queries in sqlite: https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html

A more appropriate way would be to create a connection, and then a cursor. Then you execute your queries on the cursor.

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect('example.db')
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute('SELECT * FROM users WHERE 1;')
print c.fetchone()
```

Comment: c.execute('SELECT * FROM users WHERE 1;'). what is "where 1" here?

Comment: WHERE 1 just means that we are not filtering on anything. The query in my answer just tells sqlite to fetch everything from a table called `users`

Comment: Is this the correct way??? if request.method =='POST':
  username =  request.form['username']
  password = request.form['password']
  cur = g.db.execute('select username,password from users where username=? AND password=? ',[username,password])
  g.db.commit()
  if cur.fetchone() is None:
   error='Invalid login credintials.'
  else:
   session['logged_in']=True
   return redirect(url_for('hello'))

Comment: It looks ok, are you getting any problems? If you are, please post a new question stating the problem you have. @Cyclotron3x3

Comment: my bad. My table name was 'user' and I have written 'users' in the query.So it was always returning None. Done Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML needs to be fixed:

> Attributes come in name/value pairs like: name="value"

<sup>[source](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_attributes.asp)</sup>

Your Login.html would then look like:

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block body %}
<h2>Login</h2>
{% if error %}<p class="error"><strong>Error:</strong> {{ error }}{% endif %}
<form action="{{ url_for('login') }}" method="post">
<dl>
  <dt>Username:
  <dd><input id="name" type="text" name="username">
  <dt>Password:
  <dd><input id="pass" type="password" name="password">
  <dd><input id="login" type="submit" value="Login">
  </dl>
  </form>
  {% endblock %}
```

Comment: it still allowing without authentication. Is something wrong with sqlite or python code?

Comment: See Zyber's answer, @Cyclotron3x3.